# Binding a Listbox's display and actual values to an XML node

Tags: wpf, xml, listbox, bind, xpath

I have a set of XML as follows:

```
...<spotTerms>
    <terms xmlns= "">
      <term tag="1m" display="1M"/>
      <term tag="3m" display="3M"/>
      <term tag="6m" display="6M"/>...
```

I have successfully bound a listbox to this XML using the following:

```
XmlDataProvider x:Key="Symbols" XPath="/symbols" Source="Config\Symbols.xml"/> 
...
<ListBox x:Name="SpotMonths" 
         Style="{StaticResource SymbolChooserListBox}"                                         
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Symbols}, XPath=spotTerms/terms/term/@display}"                                     
         SelectionMode="Multiple"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Background="#00000000"/>
```

My plan is to build strings depending on what items have been selected. To this end, I would like to be able to use one XML attribute for display and another for the actual string concatenation.

e.g. I would like to be able to display "1M" but use "1m" at the back end.

Can anyone help with the syntax for this?

**EDIT:** Robertos's answer helped me out. In case others have the same problem, this is the final piece of XAML I used:

```
<ListBox x:Name="SpotMonths"  
                                Style="{StaticResource SymbolChooserListBox}"                                          
                                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Terms}}"    
                                SelectedValuePath="@tag"
                                DisplayMemberPath="@display"
                                SelectionMode="Multiple" 
                                HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Background="#00000000" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The property you're looking for is [ItemsControl.DisplayMemberPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx).

Your code might look like this:

```
<XmlDataProvider x:Key="Terms" XPath="/symbols/spotTerms/terms/term" Source="Config\Symbols.xml"/> 

<ListBox x:Name="SpotMonths" 
         Style="{StaticResource SymbolChooserListBox}"                                         
         ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Terms}, XPath=@tag}"                                     
         SelectionMode="Multiple"
         HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Background="#00000000"
         DisplayMemberPath="@display" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Robertos - a very good and succinct answer! I found that if I also added a path for SelectedValuePath, I got precisely the behaviour I was looking for.